# Function to partition a list based on conditions - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and one of the exercises I'm doing is to create a function that partitions a list into three lists based on the return value of the function, so that the first sublist is obtained for the function value equal to 1, the second sublist for the function value being 2, and the third one having everything else.

The function declaration read

```
partition3 :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
partition3 _ [] = []
```

As a primer example, consider

```
partition3 (\x -> mod x 5) [1..10] = ([1,6], [2,7], [3,4,5,8,9,10])
```

Now, I have already coded the functions `filterAny`, `isSuitable`, `removeIf`, `isNotSuitable`. The full code is below:

```
filterAny :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
filterAny _ [] = []
filterAny ps (x:xs)
  | isSuitable ps x = x : filterAny ps xs
  | otherwise = filterAny ps xs

isSuitable :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
isSuitable [] _ = False
isSuitable (p:ps) v
  | p v       = True
  | otherwise = isSuitable ps v

removeIf :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
removeIf _ [] = []
removeIf ps (x:xs)
  | isNotSuitable ps x = x : removeIf ps xs
  | otherwise = removeIf ps xs

isNotSuitable :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
isNotSuitable [] _ = True
isNotSuitable (p:ps) v
  | p v       = False
  | otherwise = isNotSuitable ps v
```

Using those functions we can obtained the wanted output for `partition3`:

```
filterAny [(\x -> mod x 5 == 1)] [1..10] = [1,6]
filterAny [(\x -> mod x 5 == 2)] [1..10] = [2,7]
removeIf [even, (\x -> x > 5)] [1..10] = [3,4,5,8,9,10]
```

Unfortunately, I still haven't figured out how to write this function to output `([1,6], [2,7], [3,4,5,8,9,10])`

Comment: FWIW, `Data.List` contains `partition`, which will give you `([a], [a])`. Couldn't you use that twice to produce a `([a], ([a], [a]))`?

Comment: I am not sure if you need to use these functions. You can use explicit recursion here.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm doing some practice to learn the Haskell syntax. So I'd better not use functions already implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One high-level way to think about "creating" a value of a type like `(a,b,c)` is by thinking of the ways you have to "construct" it, like a constructor.  In this case, `(a,b,c)` has one constructor, `(_,_,_)`.  So you need to think of the things to put in the first slot, the things to put in the second slot, and the things to put in the third slot ... and you're done.

So let's outline our function like that:

```
partition3 :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
partition3 f xs = (_, _, _)
```

We know that our final answer is of the form `(_,_,_)`, where the "blanks" contain each item we want to put in our tuple.  Let's give each blank a useful name.

```
partition3 :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
partition3 f xs = (equalsOne, equalsTwo, theRest)
  where
    equalsOne = ???
    equalsTwo = ???
    theRest   = ???
```

Now you just need `equalsOne` to be the items in `xs` that match the property you want, etc.  The property for `equalsOne` is "a value `x` matches if, when you apply `f` to it, it gives `1`".  So let's write that using `filterAny`:

```
partition3 :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
partition3 f xs = (equalsOne, equalsTwo, theRest)
  where
    equalsOne = filterAny [\x -> f x == 1] xs
    equalsTwo = ???
    theRest   = ???
```

Here we filter `xs` for any items where, if you apply `f` to it, gives `1`.

Can you think of ways to implement `equalsTwo` and `theRest`, along the same lines?

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for your explanations